# In Mongodb array is there any way to insert a new element before/after a specific element position

Tags: arrays, mongodb, insert, position

Suppose i have a document like

```
{
    "_id" : 5,
    "rows": [
        { "id" : "aab", "value":100},
        { "id" : "aac", "value":400},
        { "id" : "abc", "value":200},
        { "id" : "xyz", "value":300},
    ]
}
```

and I need to insert a new sub document  into the "rows" array

```
{ "id" : "qwe", "value":300}
```

before the element position

```
{ "id" : "abc", "value":200}
```

I tried the command for insert element into a specific position using the following command

```
db.collection.update(
     {
         "_id" : 5,
         "rows.id": "abc"
     },
     {
         '$push': {
             'rows': {
                '$each': [{ "id" : "qwe", "value":300} ],
                '$position': 2
             }
         }
     }
 )
```

Its is working. But the problem is here I have to specify the

```
'$position': 2
```

which is a static value.

My requirement is to insert a new element before a particular element in the array. That is position may be dynamic value.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit of JavaScript manipulation beforehand, you could get the index of the particular array object element that you need to insert the new element before by using the map function. Firstly, get the rows array from the document using the **`findOne()`** method on the collection:

```
var rows = db.collection.findOne({"_id": 5, "rows.id": "abc"}).rows,
    pos = rows.map(function(e) { return e.id; }).indexOf("abc");
```

Then use the variable `pos` in your update statement:

```
db.collection.update(
     {
         "_id" : 5,
         "rows.id": "abc"
     },
     {
         "$push": {
             "rows": {
                "$each": [{ "id" : "qwe", "value":300} ],
                "$position": pos
             }
         }
     }
 );
```